# Laravel 5.2 dd() index color difference

Tags: colors, laravel-5

I just wanted to ask, why `dd()` function differently colours array indexes like this:

[image: laravel Dump function screen]

Please notice marked indexes. First, that is orange, second is just regular purple. Why is that for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am like 70% sure that
purple mean

```
numeric array
```

and orage mean that its

```
 associative array
```

so this

```
dd([[2=>'asd',3=>'bas'],['foo','bar']]);
```

the first array keys will be orange and the second array keys will be purple